# Block ChannelHandlerContext when I use Observable from ReplaySubject

Tags: java, networking, netty, rx-java2

I'm writing client-server application. I'm getting data from database and put it in ReplaySubject (ReplaySubject is necessary because i need to guaranteed same data on every client)  of rxjava2 when client connect subscribe to it i would like to send this data to him but when i try it in my head "possible way ^_^" it blocks. By blocks i mean it don't send data but when I shutdown server data instantly show at client side.

I try to add some threads at client and server side eventloop (I was thinking maybe thread block because i use 'Infinite' source so to receive this i need another thread or something like that).

Server side channel code:

```
public
    class ClientHandler
        extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<DataWrapper> {


    private final Observable<DataWrapper> data;

    public ClientHandler(Observable<DataWrapper> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }


    @Override
    public void channelRegistered(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        // super.channelRegistered(ctx);
        final Channel channel = ctx.channel();
        Server
            .INSTANCE
            .appendToChannelGroup(channel);

    }

    @Override
    public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        // super.channelActive(ctx);
        // i believe there is something wrong
        data.subscribe(ctx::writeAndFlush);
    }

    @Override
    public void channelReadComplete(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        ctx.flush();
    }
    // rest skip
}
```

Client side:

```
public
    class DirectNetworkCommunicator
        extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<DataWrapper> {


    private Observable<DataWrapper> generatedData;
    private ExecutorService fallbackThread;


    DirectNetworkCommunicator(Observable<DataWrapper> generatedData) {
        this.fallbackThread = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        this.generatedData = generatedData;
    }

    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
        // super.channelRead(ctx, msg);
        DataWrapper inComingData = (DataWrapper) msg;
        Adapter
            .INSTANCE
            .appendFromNettworkData(inComingData);
    }

    @Override
    public void channelReadComplete(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        // super.channelReadComplete(ctx);
        ctx.flush();
    }
    // rest skip
}
```

So how i mention before I would love it to recive data just when it become not when the server is down ^_^. If that gonna help netty version 4.1.37 final.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so future peoples face the same problem i found answer on my own. 
Netty from client side use background thread as main for communication witch means I've wait for main thread to release before it can make operation on observable.
Hope it helps someone.